# How to replace switch with polymorphism?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, enums, polymorphism

I have 2 applications: `application_1` and `applicaion_2`

`appplication_1` sends messages of different types to `application_2`

there several types. I can declare enum of these types.

```
enum MessageType{
   TYPE_1,
   TYPE_2,
   ...
}
```

In application_2 framework I use suggest me write following API

```
public void handle(Object o){
    //logic
}
```

I think about how to build classes to process each message separately.

I understand that I can declare common type for all messages:

```
abstract class AbstractMessage{
    MessageType type;
    Object o; 
    //...   
}
```

and in `application_2` inside handle I can write smth like this:

```
MessageType mt = ((AbstractMessage) o).getType();
  switch(mt){
     case TYPE_1: 
        //handle TYPE_1
        break;
     case TYPE_2: 
        //handle TYPE_2
        break;
        ....
  }
```

But this code looks ugly.

Please, help to find nicer solution.

Comment: @Downvoter, please explain what you didn't understand. I am ready to improve my question.I really strived to ask clear question

Comment: It seems what you are looking for is the [Strategy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern#Java).

Comment: @Thomas Fritsch, may be but could you provide a bit more details ?

Comment: I was thinking along @LorisSecuro's answer

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use polymorfism you could define the `abstract` message class:

```
abstract class AbstractMessage { 
    public abstract void doStuff();
    //...   
}
```

instead of using `enums`, create a class for each message type extending the abstract class and overriding the methods:

```
class Type1Message extends AbstractMessage {
    @Override
    public void doStuff() {
        //handle TYPE_1
    }
}

class Type2Message extends AbstractMessage {
    @Override
    public void doStuff() {
        //handle TYPE_2
    }
}
```

then in your `handle` method:

```
((AbstractMessage) o).doStuff();
```

Comment: I think `Message` itself shouldn't know how it will be handled. That's the responsibility of the client code to decide what to do with each type of message.

Comment: @PavloViazovskyy well, it depends I guess; also this avoids the `switch` which is what OP requested

Comment: Looks like we have 2 hierarchies. handlers and messages. Does bridge can help ?

Comment: @gstackoverflow It's only one hierarchy here. What Loris has suggested is to have `AbstractMessage` class (with subclasses for each type of message) instead of `MessageType` enum.

Comment: I didn't understand how to get object type inside concrete message

Comment: @gstackoverflow Each concrete subclass of `AbstractMessage` represents separate type of message. You just need to pass `AbstractMessage` to `application_2` handling method and call `doStuff()` on it. Concrete implementation of `doStuff()` will be polymorphically selected depending on which subclass of `AbstractMessage` was actually passed.

Comment: If you want to incorporate message-handling logic into the message class, a more succinct way to do this would be to make `AbstractMessage` an `interface` which the `MessageType` enum implements. This will allow to get rid of much of the boiler-plate.

Answer (score 0):

`application_2` anyway will need to know which type of message it has received, so some kind of `switch` is unavoidable. But the key thing is to have this `switch` ***only at one place***. For example, you could have method like following:

```
public MessageHandler getHandlerFor(MessageType messageType) {
    switch (messageType) {
        case TYPE_1: return Type1MessageHandler();
        case TYPE_2: return Type2MessageHandler();
        ............
        default: throw new IllegalArgumentException("No handler found for messageType: " + messageType);
    }
}
```

Then you will need the hierarchy of `MessageHandler`'s which correspond to *strategy* pattern:

```
public interface MessageHandler {
    void handle();
}
```

Each implementation of `MessageHandler` interface should provide `MessageType`-specific handling logic.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [chain-of-responsibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern) pattern.  It differs from the strategy pattern in that your messages are indicating commands that each application performs.  This is essentially what `switch` is doing.

You dynamically load classes that implement an interface with your `handle` method (Pavlo's class works with some modification to combine it with Loris' abstract message):

```
public interface MessageHandler
{
  void handle (AbstractMessage msg);
}
```

Java has the concept of a [service provider](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html#Service%20Provider) that is one method for dynamic loading (I'm sure there are other methods that can be used if this doesn't fit your need).  You can iterate through the handlers at the time the message is handled, passing each handler the message instance.  Each handler decides if it wants to handle the message or not.  You could even make `handle` return a `boolean` to indicate that the chain can stop calling subsequent handlers if you so wish.

You can implement handlers in each application for the message types you want to handle.  There are many ways to go about this (load the handlers and initialize each at startup, load them at time of message handling, etc) so pick the one that fits your need.  The linked service providers article has a simple loop demonstrating the loading of the handlers.

No need for a `switch` that changes as your code is modified, you just reconfigure how your jar is built.  This is also a good example of the [open-closed principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle) where your code does not change but is open to extension.

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like below. it does have a switch, but the code for each type is together in the enum.

```
public class So43459907 {
    public enum Type {
        m1 {
            @Override Object create(Object o) {
                return o;
            }
            @Override void handle(Object o) {}
        },
        m2 {
            @Override Object create(Object o) {
                return o;
            }
            @Override void handle(Object o) {}
        };
        abstract Object create(Object o);
        abstract void handle(Object o);
        public static Object create(Type type,Object o) {
            switch(type) {
                case m1:
                    return m1.create(o);
                case m2:
                    return m2.create(o);
                default:
                    throw new RuntimeException("oops");
            }
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```